# How to show random words from a text file on multiple labels in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a text file of words and i make it to read in my project its fine, now i want to split words strings in half and show randomly on multiple labels which i make on my view.

```
    NSString *myfilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"textFile" ofType:@"txt"];

NSString *linesFromFile = [[NSString alloc]   initWithContentsOfFile:myfilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

myWords = [NSArray alloc];
myWords = [linesFromFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

NSLog(@"%@", myWords);
```

I make 5 labels how can i make my text file words to split and appear randomly on these five labels?

Comment: do the text on the label will change per time frame? if not how can you show up your whole texts in your text-file.

Comment: yes it should change randomly.....

Comment: can two labels or more show the same text at the same time?

Comment: yes and this is the problem..

Comment: do you mean can not show the same text at the same time?

Comment: no man i mean it show same text at same time

Comment: i actually want to split one string of words in half and then show it randomly on label...say i have a word Apple and i have 2 labels then i want string App on one label and  string le on second label that is the problem

Comment: and the left 3 label show nothing if the word is `Apple`, alright?

Comment: yes like this ....do you know why?

Comment: can you please tell me how i can show App on one label and le on second label ..... i mean to split a word string in two labels

Comment: oh yeah, but you have 5 labels, if the word is long, you can let 5 labels all show the word spit ?

Comment: i mean when we join two labels it make one real word... do you understand?the label size should be according to word length

Comment: some thing like[ https://www.raywenderlich.com/33806/how-to-make-a-letterword-game-with-uikit-part-2] but it make all letters one by one and in my case i want string in two parts to show in different labels

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138301/discussion-between-john-and-aircraft).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS -Sergey recommend half of my problem solved i am able to show a word string of text file on label. remove this labels[i].text from code and call

```
NSMutableArray<UILabel*>* labels = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *words = [myWords mutableCopy];
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 70*i, 100, 40)];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
     //whatever other properties

    NSInteger index = arc4random()%words.count;
    label.text = words[index];
    [words removeObjectAtIndex:index];


    [self.view addSubview:label];
    [labels addObject: label];


}
```

This shows a full string of word now i want to split a word string in two parts for example if i have a word Apple it should be split in as App and le  and show it randomly appear on different labels any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this

```
  NSMutableArray *words = [myWords mutableCopy];
  for (int i = 0; i<5 ;i++)
  {
    NSInteger index = arc4random()%words.count;
    labels[i].text = words[index];
    [words removeObjectAtIndex:index];
  }
```

Comment: what will be the method to read array elements for object UILabel?

Comment: What you mean? You say you already have 5 labels, so you need to create array with this labels, some thing like this: `NSArray<UILabel*>* labels = @[label1,label2,label3,label4,label5];`

Comment: oh i created labels with loop for (int i = 1; i<5; i++) {   UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 70*i, 100, 40)];
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; }

Comment: Ok. Create variable `NSMutableArray<UILabel*>* labels = [NSMutableArray array]` and call `[labels addObject: label]` in loop body.

Comment: Or you can to fill text in this loop. Add this `NSMutableArray *words = [myWords mutableCopy];` before loop and this `NSInteger index = arc4random()%words.count;label.text = words[index]; [words removeObjectAtIndex:index];` in loop body after you created and configured label.

Comment: Thanks it work .... it shows a complete word on label what if i want to show App-le on two lables i mean App on label1 and le on lable2 and so on?